# mongodb C# use lookup and facet for count

Tags: c#, mongodb, count

I have this code:

```
var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
            {
            new BsonDocument("$lookup",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "from", "comments" },
                    { "let",
            new BsonDocument("id", "$_id") },
                { "pipeline",
            new BsonArray
                    {
                        new BsonDocument("$match",
                        new BsonDocument("$expr",
                        new BsonDocument("$eq",
                        new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        "$postId",
                                        "$$id"
                                    }))),
                        new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument("time", -1)),
                        new BsonDocument("$limit", Filters.defaultCommentsLimitPerPost),
                    }
                },
                    { "as", "comments" }
                }),
            new BsonDocument("$limit", 3),
            new BsonDocument("$skip", page - 1),
            };

var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Post, Post>.Create(Filters.GetJoinComments(page));
                var result = await collectionPosts.Aggregate(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```

How can I also get the total count of all documents, ignoring $limit and $skip?

an example for a post document:

```
{"_id":null,"time":{"$numberLong":"637396703347196085"},"text":"some text","totalCommentsCount":{"$numberInt":"0"},"likes":{"$numberInt":"0"},"category":{"$numberInt":"0"},"videoUrl":null}
```

an example for a comment document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f9dbaf79d10c42f64f46f53"},"text":"a comment","time":{"$numberLong":"637397765330317024"},"likes":{"$numberInt":"0"},"postId":{"$oid":"5f9089dd818de4309403d21b"}}
```

Comment: Inside the pipeline you can use group to find all records, then unwind it. else you can use facet to that. If you dont understand , please post your sample data

Comment: Not sure where to put the facet and what its syntax is exactly. I have 'post' documents and 'comment' documents. a 'comment' document has a 'postId' field. So you can see in the $lookup that I join by the comment's postId to the post's _id, then sort the comments by time and limit for X comments. Later I limit and skip the posts. What I want, is to know the total count of posts.

Comment: Why don you post sample both collections without explaining it. It would be better for others too

Comment: @varman I edited the question and added examples.

Answer (score 0):

The query you tried is very much appreciated.

I have additionally added

- `$sort` to osrt by _id. If you don't need, remove the sort
- `$group` to group all documents into `data` (Because `_id:null`). At the same time we get the total counts.
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `data` array
- I thin you use this for pagination, right? If so, you need to keep `$sort` and first should be `$skip`, following should be `$limit` as I mentioned

And the working query.

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comment",
      let: {
        "pId": "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$postId",
                "$$pId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "comments"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { _id: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      totalRecords: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $skip: 1 },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b8G-K17iNpV)**

Comment: You know how I should translate the $group to c# aggregation builders? I tried something like "new BsonDocument("$group", new BsonDocument({{"_id", ",...". Isn't a better way is to use $facet? And you also don't limit the number of comments, I guess it's just to add $sort and $limit in the pipeline.

Comment: @RonyTesler Does the answer help you

Comment: I couldn't really use it, sorry. Not sure how to write it in BsonDocument[], and I think $facet is the right choice here.

Comment: Superb.. keep improving it